# how to make a single button that changes from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: javascript, html, css

my assignment is to create a single button that changes the text in a text entry box to all uppercase and all lowercase in html and javascript.  when the page is reloaded, it goes back to the default that the value that the text entry is.  the button name is also supposed to change when clicked (so like when the button was clicked and the text is now all uppercase, the button name should change to "lower" so that when you click it it would change the text back to lower.  and once at lower the button name should change to "UPPER"). the button is also supposed to be centered, and we are supposed to make a function in javascript to do this.  this is the html code of my text entry box:

```
<p align="center" style="font-weight: normal;"> Question: <input type="text" name="URL" value="Where will the URL be displayed?" size=30 readonly> </p>
```

and this is the code i have so far for the button (i don't have a function name yet and im not sure what to put for the value yet):

```
 <p align="center" style="font-weight: normal;"> <input type="button" value="???" name="uplow" onClick="function_name();" </p>
```

i am pretty much open to any answers, and thank you for the help !!!

Comment: Do you want to switch the text of button to lowercase when input value is in uppercase or want to change the text to uppercase when the input value is in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button text and input value according to your requirement.

You can use this `value` property to `get` and `set` property of any input.

you can change the button text to `uppercase` and `lowercase` using the `style` property of an element.

I've used the button name as `send`, you could use any name.

```js
let isUpper = false;

const questionInput = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
const button = document.querySelector('input[type=button]');

// Default condition, so make the button text to uppercase
button.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (isUpper) {
    e.target.style.textTransform = 'uppercase';
    questionInput.value = questionInput.value.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    e.target.style.textTransform = 'lowercase';
    questionInput.value = questionInput.value.toUpperCase();
  }
  isUpper = !isUpper;
})
```

```html
<p align="center" style="font-weight: normal;"> Question:
  <input type="text" name="URL" value="Where will the URL be displayed?" size=30 readonly>
</p>

<p align="center" style="font-weight: normal;">
  <input type="button" value="send" name="uplow" />
</p>
```